# How to access this function in javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps

I am trying to reach a function inside an other function from a global point.

Here the example

```
A(function B{...}, function C{...});
...
B();
```

I am wondering if it is possible? If not how can i move my function around so i can reach it, i am also doing it because it has to be synchronous. The function are for google maps so i can add listener in my maps or respond to it.

Here more the real code

```
if(navigator.geolocation)
{
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){...},function geocode_lookup( type, value, update ){...});
}
...
geocode_lookup(t1,t2,t3);
```

Thanks for any inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because of closures, the function is only available within the scope of the other function. If you want it to be accessible from the global scope, you can either return it from the function or called within the function itself or have it accesed as a prototype

Comment: Thanks, well this is sad in my moment of javascript, but yeah it make sense i will mark this answer as good when allowed

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I understand the question, so here's an answer based on what I understand.

```
function B{...}
function C{...}

A(B, C);
...

B();
```